# How to implement IF-ELSE statement to change the cell value using app script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In here I am trying to change the cell value based on the IF-ELSE statement.

As you can see in the picture below, when user try to run the script for the  first time, few files from google drive will be listed in the sheet with the **STATUS** mark as **"new file"** (row 2 till 5).

However, if there is any new files been uploaded into the google drive, user will run a script "check new files" to populate only the **uploaded new files into the google sheet** (row 6 and 7). But their **STATUS** mark is blank as shown in the picture.

[image]

Therefore i used the IF-ELSE statement, to convert the **STATUS** of row 2 till 5 ("**"new file"** into **"old file"**") AND the blank row of 6 and 7 as **"new file"**.

Here is the code:

```
function updateMarker(){
var sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var cellValue = sheet.getRange("C2:C"+ sheet.getLastRow()).getValue(); 
Logger.log(cellValue);

if (cellValue == 'new file'){
sheet.getRange("C2:C"+ sheet.getLastRow()).setValue('OLD FILE');
 }
if(cellValue == '' ){
sheet.getRange("C2:C"+ sheet.getLastRow()).setValue('NEW FILE');
 }
  }
```

If i run the code, it converts the whole cell value from row 2 till 7 as **"old file"**. Which i guess it detects only the first if statement `if (cellValue == 'new file')`.

**My goal is**

1. to convert the "new file" marker into "old file"
2. to set the empty cell value of the new uploaded files as "new file"

How can i solve this problem?

**AFTER IMPLEMENTING THE SOLUTION CODE GIVEN**
[image]

[image]

After i run for 2nd and 3rd time the **STATUS** changes vice versa.

Isn't the **STATUS** changes only if the cell value is **"new file"** and if there is **empty** cell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) on a range of more than one cell will only return the value in the upper-left most cell in the range.

So the line

```
var cellValue = sheet.getRange("C2:C"+ sheet.getLastRow()).getValue()
```

actually just sets `cellValue` to the value in `C2`, or `'new file'`.

This makes the line:

```
if (cellValue == 'new file')
```

always evaluate to true, so all cells are changed.

#### Modifications:

- Use [`.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) instead of `getValue()`
- Loop through all the cells
- [Set](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) the new `OLD FILE/NEW FILE` array back to the column range

```
function updateMarker() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")

  const cells = sheet.getRange("C2:C" + sheet.getLastRow())
  const cellValues = cells.getValues()
  Logger.log(cellValues)

  const newValues = []

  cellValues.forEach((row) => {
    if (row[0] === "new file") {
      newValues.push(['OLD FILE'])
    }
    else if (row[0] === "OLD FILE" || row[0] === "NEW FILE") {
      newValues.push([row[0]])
    }
    else {
      newValues.push(['NEW FILE'])
    }
  })
  
  cells.setValues(newValues)
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying, i notice that when i rerun the script for second and third time `['OLD FILE']` and `['NEW FILE']` changes vice versa. For example if the first time i run the script the (**"new file"** changes into **'OLD FILE'**) while the (**blank space** is filled with **'NEW FILE'** ). But when i run for second time all the **'OLD FILE'** changes into  **'NEW FILE'** meanwhile **'NEW FILE'** changes into **'OLD FILE'**.

Comment: How can i set in the `else { newValues.push(['NEW FILE'])}` here,  else the row is **_empty_** then push the value(['NEW FILE'])?? how can we write this? At least it will check for only two conditions..one is for the (if "new files") and another one (else "empty")

Comment: I tried the code and I am getting this error "**Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 5.** (line 41 =`cells.setValues(newValues)` ) "

Comment: @VishnuKumaran i think it should be fixed now

Comment: Hello @I hope this is helpful to you, can i know how can i set the background color once we push the "NEW FILE"(green) and "OLD FILE"(red)?
i tried implementing, `var backGrounds = []` , `backGrounds.push(['00ff00'])`, `cells.setValues(newValues).setBackground(backGrounds)`. But it doesnt work. Can i know how we do that on the code above?

Comment: @VishnuKumaran I think this would be better answered if posted as a new question :)